# Geometric Condition for Harmonic Function

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Under what geometric condition on real harmonic functions u and v on a region G is the function uv also harmonic?

Comment: Take a look here: https://math.temple.edu/~tewodros/solutions/10651.PDF